# Horizontal (inline) list in HTML/CSS with divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple horizontal list, where each list item is a div and I want them all to sit next to one another. When I try to use the code below though, the divs end up on separate lines. Here's what I've got:

HTML:

```
<ul id="navlist">
<li><div>...</div></li>
<li><div>...</div></li>
<li><div>...</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

I have tried to give my divs a max width and a width but that doesn't work either. Basically, they show up without bullet points on separate lines.

Some help on fixing this would be very appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#navlist li { display:inline }
#navlist div { display:inline }
```

Making the `<li>` inline while leaving the `<div>` as block is your problem.

Alternatively, you may want `inline-block` for the `<li>` if you are going to be controlling sizes or margins.

You may also be interested in this demo: http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html

*I'm not sure why you have `<div>` inside your `<li>`, but I presume you have your reasons.*

Comment: So I ended up just setting #navlist li to display: inline-block. worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    background: #48D;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
li div {
    background: #6AF;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><div>Text</div></li>
    <li><div>Text</div></li>
    <li><div>Text</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each div inside the list items is displayed as a block by default. Display them inline as well and it should work.

```
#navlist div, #navlist li
{
  display: inline;
}
#navlist li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `float: left;` on the list items, perhaps something like that:

```
#navlist li
{
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Also, make sure to specify a height to the ul because the elements will go out of the flow, meaning that the ul won't have any height. You can also use a clearfix to fix this behavior:

```
.clear:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clear
{
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clear
{
    display: block;
}

* html .clear
{
    height: 1%;
}
```

You just add `class="clear"` to the `<ul>`. Google clearfix css for more infos :)