# How to make a horizontal list with divs?

Tags: list, html

I am trying to make a simple  list  , in which there will be 3 divs.
I can not do that, although I did exactly what in this topic was mentioned :

[Horizontal (inline) list in HTML/CSS with divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437790/horizontal-inline-list-in-html-css-with-divs)

The divs appear vertical and I can not imagine why.

Do you know any other way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you set them to `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: Yes I did: ul#navlist li { display:inline; }

Comment: You should add some code, possibly a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/), perhaps the problem isn't directly where you're looking.

Comment: Did you set the interior divs to display:inline as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BwRrZ/1/ ,it is the first time I use this jsfiddle but I think I did it right.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `display: inline` or `float: left` they will probably appear horizontal.

Comment: add this css: .topic {display: inline}

Comment: It made my divs disappear. I change their color, their place but still disappeared.

Comment: Ok it worked when I put some images inside the divs. I had given them height: 200px width: 200px and background-color and they went disappear but when I put some images inside they appeared. Thanks!

Comment: If you use display: inline-block instead of display: inline I think your height and width values will work.

Answer (score 2):

1. using display: inline; is not the same as using inline-block.
2. It looks like you're trying to to display list-items, not divs inline.

If #2 is correct, you need to make sure that you use display: inline-block, not display: inline.

Also, from your code, you'll want to make sure your ul element has an id="navlist" ... The same style will not work for all other UL elements in the document.