# HTML / JS horizontal scrolling DIV "list"

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to make is an horizontally scrolling DIV "list" just like pretty much every big web site in the internet(netflix for example).

I tried to make it using a main DIV which would be some kind of container, a 2nd div which holds all the content and is inside the first DIV and a lot of DIVs, one for each content module, that go inside the 2nd div.
the parts of the 2nd DIV that overflow the main one should hide, and the content could be shown by moving it(the 2nd DIV).

this is the best I could come up with, but it still doesn't work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96gcw/1/)

This is my HTML

```
<button onmouseover="left=1" onmouseout="left=0">
    <</button>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="filler" style="left:0px">
                <div class="module" style="background:coral;">testing</div>
                <div class="module" style="background:lightblue;">testing</div>
                <div class="module" style="background:lightgreen;">testing</div>
                <div class="module" style="background:salmon;">testing</div>
                <div class="module" style="background:lightyellow;">testing</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onmouseover="right=1" onmouseout="right=0">></button>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#filler {
    height:50px;
    width:250px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:crimson;
}
.module {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:5px;
    float:left;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var feft = 0
//feft stands for filler left
var right = 0
var left = 0

var loaded = 0

window.onload=function(){

loaded=1

}

function move() {

    if(loaded == 1){
        if (left == 1 && feft <= 250) {
            //left == 1 && feft <= filler width
            document.getElementById("filler").style.left = feft + 1
        }
        if (right == 1 && feft >= 0) {
            //right == 1 && feft >= 0 
            document.getElementById("filler").style.left = feft - 1
        } //these IFs tests if the filler should move 
        feft = document.getElementById("filler").style.left
        //this sets the feft variable to what it needs to be for the next run of the function  
    }}

window.setInterval(move(), 100)
```

Comment: Please post this to jsfiddle.net for us to try.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery there are lots of horizontal scroll menu/showcase jQuery plugins available: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/horizontal-scroller

Comment: Also check out http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/ depending on how "dynamic" you want it; this is another approach.

Comment: Or if this is what you are looking for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652879/how-to-make-a-horizontal-list-with-divs . It's somewhat unclear (at least to me) what you mean by "scrolling DIV list \" just like pretty every big website\"."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a fiddle for you.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49sYB/)

HTML code

```
<button onmouseover="left=1" onClick="move(-1)"><</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="filler" style="left:0px">
            <div class="module" style="background:coral;">testing</div>
            <div class="module" style="background:lightblue;">testing</div>
            <div class="module" style="background:lightgreen;">testing</div>
            <div class="module" style="background:salmon;">testing</div>
            <div class="module" style="background:lightyellow;">testing</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button onmouseover="right=1" onClick="move(1)">></button>
```

JS Code

```
var position = 0;
var moduleCount = document.querySelector(".module").length;
window.move = function(number) {
    if (number) {
       position += number;
        if (number == 0 || number > moduleCount) {
            position = 0;
        }
    } else {        
        if (position <= 4) {
            position++;
        } else {
            position = 0;
        }
    }
    moduleOffset =  document.querySelector(".module").offsetWidth;
    filler = document.querySelector("#filler");
    filler.style.left = -( position* moduleOffset) + "px";
}
setInterval(window.move, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: scroll` as a CSS property to your container div.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "Carousel". I suggest to use bootstrap for example and implement it then in your site.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel