# Div list horizontaly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to create a list to code with `javascript` as you can see here :

[What I want to do](http://test.brunotarhan.fr/liste.php)

However, I can't figure how to code this using html and css. I've tried multiple way found here,on this site, or otherwhere on the net.

I found a way to "align them" but they are not centered.

You can see my actual code here :

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2">Content2</div>
<div id="div3">Content3</div>
<div id="div4">Content4</div>
<div id="div5">Content5</div>
<div id="div6">Content6</div>
<div id="div7">Content7</div>
</div>


#div1 div{
width: 65px;
height: 100px;
margin-left:2%;
float:left;
color: white;
align:center; 
}

#div1{
margin:0px auto;
width:500px;
height: 100px;
background-color:black;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: can you please paste your code here

Comment: @TamilSelvan I don't have any images yet, i just would like to create the blocs i show on the image. Only then, i'll add the images.

Comment: So the beginning is your body code and below is the css, should there be more code or is it's  just it? I'm asking because the css only has div1

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you are looking something like below

```css
.box{
    background-color: #53BBFB;
    float: left;
    height: 74px;
    margin: 15px 5px 5px 0;
    padding-top: 22px;
    width: 181px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="box">Content1</div>
<div id="div2" class="box">Content2</div>
<div id="div3" class="box">Content3</div>
<div id="div4" class="box">Content4</div>
<div id="div5" class="box">Content5</div>
<div id="div6" class="box">Cont
```

Check it working here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvoLWG

EDIT:
If you are looking something like the image you have in link, then try below

```css
.box{    
    float: left;    
    margin: 15px 5px 5px 0;
    padding-top: 22px;    
    text-align:center;
}
.grid-box1 {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  height: 30px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-top:40px;
}
.grid-box2 {
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  margin-top:35px;
}

.grid-box3 {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-top:30px;
}
.grid-box4 {
  background-color: #A1A1A1;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="box grid-box1">Content1</div>
<div id="div2" class="box grid-box2">Content2</div>
<div id="div3" class="box grid-box3">Content3</div>
<div id="div4" class="box grid-box4">Content4</div>
<div id="div5" class="box grid-box3">Content5</div>
<div id="div6" class="box grid-box2">Content6</div>
<div id="div7" class="box grid-box1">Content7</div>
```

Check it working here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvoLmv

Comment: This seems to be very good indeed. I'll try with this, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating the elements, use `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center` on the parent container.

```css
#div1 div {
  width: 65px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0% 2%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
#div1 {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">Content2</div>
  <div id="div3">Content3</div>
  <div id="div4">Content4</div>
  <div id="div5">Content5</div>
  <div id="div6">Content6</div>
  <div id="div7">Content7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use UL and LI that way you control your margins.
I've seen that this have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437790/horizontal-inline-list-in-html-css-with-divs) before.

Code snippet from the previous question:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul {
background: #48D;
height: 35px;
line-height: 25px;
width: 300px;
}
li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
li div {
background: #6AF;
padding: 0 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><div>Text</div></li>
<li><div>Text</div></li>
<li><div>Text</div></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, however, the three blocs are not centered in the div... do you know how I can figure this out ?

Comment: @Ezhno, Just add "text-align:center;" to UL and replace "float:left;" with "display:inline-block;"

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I can horizontally align them ? I changed the height of some but they are aligning on top of the main div...

Comment: @Ezhno, you can remove the margin from the "li" and use "padding" as you desire. Example: "padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px"

Comment: @Ezhno, please mark the right answer for your question so other can get use of it.